# Firebase login swiftui

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

Using firebase for a login authentication in my IOS Application i used the code below to for execution of my login within my content view.

i want to know why that when i simulate my application on my iPhone once a  user signs up with a new account they are automatically logged into the application?

Shouldn't it be that once a user signs up a new account in my IOS application that they have to sign in to then get logged in to their new account?

```
// Code for authentication to sign a user into my application.

Group {
            if (session.session != nil) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Welcome")
                  

.font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                    Button(action:session.signOut) {
                        Text("Sign out")
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                SignInView().environmentObject(SessionStore())
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: getUser)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. When you step through the code you shared in a debugger, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do? Keep in mind that we can only see what you shared, so it's important that you provide enough context for the problem.

Comment: i edited my question @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: if it's still unclear let me reframe itt again then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication's client-side SDKs (like the one you're using for iOS) automatically sign the new user account. From research the team did before defining this API it is the more common use-case for client-side authentication, over the separate create-acount-then-signin flow that you expect.

Comment: so are you saying its normal for functionality wise for new users to just be logged in once they've signed up? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Also @Frank van Puffelen how do i store users ids in firestore so that once a user is logged in they have access only to their data.